# Multiple fill for a control

Tags: java, japplet

I want to fill a control to `HORIZONTAL` and the `CENTER` using GridBagLayout. I have tried using

```
this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints m=new GridBagConstraints();
m.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
m.anchor=GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
m.ipady=20;
m.weightx=0.5;
m.weighty=0.001;
add(pnlHeader,m);
m.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL|GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
m.anchor=GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
m.gridx=0;
m.weighty=1.0;
add(pnlBody,m);
```

This is what I get

[image]

I want the selected area to filled into the applet. Please How can I fill the second panel into the applet?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
m.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

Comment: Please I want to anchor to `PAGE_START` and `LEFT`?. Please how do I do it?

Comment: That probably deserves a new question - in the new question be sure to describe what you're aiming (image perhaps) for and include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)